Matplotlib arrows do not have proper length
I have subset of countries where I am comparing gdp per person and geographic latitude.  I've developed code down here:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('font', size=12)
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=14, titlesize = 14)
plt.rc('legend', fontsize =12)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=10)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=10)

country_sub.plot(kind='scatter', figsize=(6, 4), grid=True, x=lat_col, y=gdp_ppp_col)

gdp_ppp_col = "gdp_ppp"
lat_col = "lat"

min_gdp_ppp = 25
max_gdp_ppp = 125_000

position_text = {
    "Israel": (31.04605, 57_758),
    "United States": (37.09024, 75_269),
    "Spain": (40.463667, 29_385),
    "Bulgaria": (42.733883, 13_129),
    "Germany": (51.165691, 48_845),
    "Ireland": (53.41291, 105_362),
    "Iceland": (64.963051, 74_663)
}

for country, pos_text in position_text.items():
    pos_data_x = country_sub[lat_col].loc[country]
    pos_data_y = country_sub[gdp_ppp_col].loc[country]
    country = "U.S." if country == "United States" else country
    plt.annotate(country, xy=(pos_data_x, pos_data_y),
        xytext=pos_text, fontsize=12,
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=3,
            shrink=0.08, headwidth=5))
    plt.plot(pos_data_x, pos_data_y, "ro")

plt.axis([min_lat, max_lat, min_gdp_ppp, max_gdp_ppp])

plt.show()

This results in the graph below:

However there are no stems on my arrows.  I've tried altering the arrow plot parameters with no success.
I am trying to create something that looks more like this:

From: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2024/02/scatter-plot-visualization-in-python-using-matplotlib/

You should try adding arrowstyle='->' to arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=3, shrink=0.08, headwidth=5). You should have something like this:
plt.annotate(
    country, 
    xy=(pos_data_x, pos_data_y),
    xytext=pos_text, 
    fontsize=12,
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=3, shrink=0.08, headwidth=5, arrowstyle='->')
)

